# Post to user's wall as if it is them posting

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I have an app and I am able to post to a user's wall when they allow it. However, when the app makes a wall post, it shows that it is from me (the administrator of the app) posting on the user's wall. I want it to look like it was the actual user posting on their own wall... (using VS 2008, .Net 3.5)

Here is my code...

```
    Dim oFB As Facebook.FacebookClient
    Dim sAppId As String = "my app id"
    Dim sAppSecret As String = "it's a secret"

    Dim webClient As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
    Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" & sAppId & "&client_secret=" & sAppSecret & "&grant_type=client_credentials")

    '- Access token changes every hour
    oFB = New Facebook.FacebookClient(sAppId, sAppSecret)

    oFB.AccessToken = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("=") + 1)

    Dim oPost As Collections.Generic.IDictionary(Of String, Object)
    oPost = New Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    oPost.Add("message", "(websitepipeline test post) Check out this new product!") '- This is the wall post / the description input for the DM function
    oPost.Add("link", "http://www.example.com/content/somepage.html")
    oPost.Add("from", "the user who authenticated")
    oFB.Post("the user who authenticated/feed", oPost)
```

Comment: Wait wait wait... are you making a spam app >:(

Comment: I'm using the facebook sdk (http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/). I'm only posting content selected by user's who have authenticated my app. I'll check out that link you (dan) posted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to a library someone made for .NET that it wraps around ;) [link]http://www.lagorio.net/windows/facebook/) Obviously you will need to present a FBDialog asking the user for his credentials of course! :) Not too sure what library your using but maybe the string for "from" is incorrect or needs to be a user token of some sort

Use the .setStatus command w/ this API.

Comment: This one works, but it posts "is..." on the front of everything. :(

Comment: Isn't there a: includesVerb argument on setStatus? doesn't that remove it? _fbService.Users.SetStatus(text, /* includesVerb */ true);

Comment: Sweet! That was it... 
        Parameters.Add("status_includes_verb", True)